# Getting all retweets with twitter gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter

I want to use twitter gem for getting retweets of original tweet. I want to getting all of retweets in case of I give the original status id to twitter api. Is there any way to do this with twitter gem. I didn't find any solution

Comment: How you are getting original tweet id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**twitter**](https://github.com/sferik/twitter) gem.

Add it into your Gemfile and run `bundle install`.

Now you need to initialize twitter rest client.

```
client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
  config.consumer_key        = "YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY"
  config.consumer_secret     = "YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET"
  config.access_token        = "YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN"
  config.access_token_secret = "YOUR_ACCESS_SECRET"
end


# @param tweet [Integer, String, URI, Twitter::Tweet] A Tweet ID, URI, or object.
# @param options [Hash] A customizable set of options.
# @option options [Integer] :count Specifies the number of records to retrieve.
# Must be less than or equal to 100.
# @option options [Boolean, String, Integer] :trim_user Each tweet returned in a 
# timeline will include a user object with only the author's numerical ID when set
# to true, 't' or 1.

retweets = client.retweets(original_tweet_id, options = {})
```

You can **[read more](https://github.com/sferik/twitter/blob/master/README.md#configuration)** and here is the [**API console proof**](https://apigee.com/console/twitter?authTypeVal=oauth1&afterSuccessfulAuth=true&req=%7B%22resource%22%3A%22statuses_retweets%22%2C%22params%22%3A%7B%22query%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22template%22%3A%7B%22id%22%3A%2212331%22%7D%2C%22headers%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22body%22%3A%7B%22attachmentFormat%22%3A%22mime%22%2C%22attachmentContentDisposition%22%3A%22form-data%22%7D%7D%2C%22verb%22%3A%22get%22%7D) (It will ask for twitter authentication to show data)